# Conversion failed when converting date & time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am storing current system date and time in database.while running this error will occur.
this is my coding..
i am using datetype as date in my database

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
TextBox5.Text = d.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I don't see any database. Please post the relevant code and the exact error.

Comment: *this error will occur* ? What error? post exception details and also the relevant code. Am pretty sure this is not the relevant code

Comment: it's probably better to use a timestamp (provided by your database) for storing the current datetime